# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session when I use EAGER initalization

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have hibernate mapping:

Prepod:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prepod")
public class Prepod {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        id = i;
    }
}
```

and Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long age;
    private List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Prepod> getPrepods() {
        return prepods;
    }

    public void setPrepods(List<Prepod> prepods) {
        this.prepods = prepods;
    }

    public Student() {
        name = null;
    }

    public Student(Student s) {
        name = s.getName();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public Long getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        id = i;
    }

    public void setName(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public void setAge(Long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

invocation code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Prepod prepod = (Prepod) session.load(Prepod.class, 1l);
        Student student = (Student) session.load(Student.class, 1l);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.close();
                List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(student);

        List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
        prepods.add(prepod);

        prepod.setStudents(students);//exception here
        student.setPrepods(prepods);
....
```

When I invoke code above I see next trace:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException:
>   could not initialize proxy - no Session   at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
>     at
>   logic.Prepod_$$_javassist_1.setStudents(Prepod_$$_javassist_1.java)
>     at logic.Main.main(Main.java:38)

What is the cause of this problem?

The state of my objects is detached in two last rows?

How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

after good advice for editing code from Prabhakaran I have next question:

If I update student  - note doesn't added to intermediate table of database but another behavior if I make update for prepod entity. It was happened because prepod is owner of relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Prepod prepod = null;
    Student  student = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    prepod = (Prepod) session.load(Prepod.class, 1l);
    student = (Student) session.load(Student.class, 1l);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(student);

    List<Prepod> prepods = new ArrayList<Prepod>();
    prepods.add(prepod);

    prepod.getStudents().addAll(students);//exception here
    student.getPrepods().addAll(prepods);
```

Comment: Error creating Session: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship: logic.Student.prepods
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at logic.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:51)
 at logic.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal use of mappedBy on both sides of the relationship: logic.Student.prepods